How do I create E2E tests for an Electron app?
I'm working with an Electron app that I need to create an end to end test for.
I have experience writing e2e test in Playwright for browser based apps. Playwright allows you to test your app on several browser emulators they provide.
I was wondering if there's a way to test an Electron app on different OS, because it's not possible with Playwright.
Is there an established consensus about this already? I'm thinking I can run three docker containers that run the test on different OS using docker-compose. But I'm not sure if this is in fact a respectable way of doing this.
My current idea is to have my npm test script run 'docker-compose up --build' and that would start 3 containers on different OS that would copy the repo to the continaer, install dependencies, build and and run tests.
What do you think? Thank you!
